# Workaround for MySQL limited TIMESTAMP range while reserving its auto timezone conversion feature?

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timezone, timestamp

What I want is:
 1. When a transaction is performed, the current time is recorded
 2. Timezone info is also stored so that the time will be converted automatically based on client-side timezone

So TIMESTAMP sounds like a perfect choice for me, but it turns out that the range is too small (1970-2038) for applications that need to stand long. So I wonder how I can get around this limitation. I know that DATETIME has a much wider range, but it doesn't seem to fulfill requirement no. 2, may I have your ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need to store the timezone offset in a separate field and store using a `DATETIME` that's represented in UTC as you should for all dates and times unless you have a very good reason.

The full time-zone name would need to be expressed because the time-zone offset alone is not as meaningful. For example, -0400 could refer to Eastern Daylight Time or Central Standard Time.

Comment: tadman, your method is reasonable, but what about the automatic timezone conversion provided by MySQL for TIMESTAMP data type? I don't want to do the conversion (which has to consider the daylight time) by myself since it's error-prone, is there any workaround for this?

Comment: It's actually not clear that the `TIMESTAMP` data type actually contains time-zone data. The [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) implies that for `TIMESTAMP` the conversion is done to and from local time-zone where the data is always stored in UTC. The time-zone offset is only stored as a connection or server parameter, not in the database itself. It's probably best do to time-zone conversion in your application and it's not hard to do if you have a library that can do this for you, a standard feature on most OSes.

Comment: I see. your answer with this comment is convincing enough for me to accept it as best answer. Thx!